# Rails regex with include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm finding MX records based on a user's email to determine if they use Gmail. The MX server records come back like this:

```
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com
ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.com
ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com
alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

Where non Google mail servers send back stuff like:

```
mx2.emailsrvr.com
mx1.emailsrvr.com
nil
```

What is a good way to determine if one of the MX records contain a Google MX record? I've been trying:

```
  if mx.any? {|server| server.exchange.to_s.include? "google"} then
    return true
  end
```

This doesn't work as it requires an exactly match. Any elegant ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `mx` is an Array:

```
mx.any? { |server| server.exchange.to_s.downcase.include? "google" }
```

Should work.  As an aside, because the `any?` method returns `true` or `false` you don't need to explicitly return `true`, just return the value of the `any?` method.

Example:

```
[
  "ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com", 
  "ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com", 
  "ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com", 
  "ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.com", 
  "ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com", 
  "alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 
  "alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 
  "alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 
  "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 
  "alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com" 
]
array.any? { |server| server.include? "google" }
# => true
array.any? { |server| server.downcase.include? "google" }
# => true
array.all? { |server| server.include? "google" }
# => false
array.all? { |server| server.downcase.include? "google" }
# => true
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't that require an exact match?

Comment: Yea, that's why you call `#downcase` on the the string first, so that the lowercase instances of `"google"` will match.